# Sorting dataframe over

Tags: python, pandas

I was transforming tables with pandas and after a groupby and sum-aggregation on costs, I got a dataframe like this:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║ Section ║ Description ║ Month ║ Group ║ Cost_2018 ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     1 ║     0 ║       500 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     1 ║     1 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     1 ║     4 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     1 ║    93 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     2 ║     0 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     2 ║     1 ║       630 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     2 ║     4 ║       530 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     2 ║    93 ║       110 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     3 ║     0 ║       190 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     3 ║     1 ║       110 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     3 ║     4 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     3 ║    93 ║         0 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

But I would like to have the groups together and the months repeating, like this:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║ Section ║ Description ║ Month ║ Group ║ Cost_2018 ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     1 ║     0 ║       500 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     2 ║     0 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     3 ║     0 ║       190 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     1 ║     1 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     2 ║     1 ║       630 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     3 ║     1 ║       110 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     1 ║     4 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     2 ║     4 ║       530 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     3 ║     4 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     1 ║    93 ║         0 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     2 ║    93 ║       110 ║
║ A3      ║ Cleaning    ║     3 ║    93 ║         0 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

I would like it sorted with the Sections and Descriptions together as this is only a part of a very big df and whenever I tried to sort it, either the Sections or Descriptions would mix with others.

Comment: `df.sort_values(["Group","Month"])`.

Comment: thank you very much, I was trying around with this function. I finally got it the way I wanted by using `df.sort_values(['Section','Description','Group','Month'])`